# Letter spacing for fonts in terminal / gvim at 7pt

Tags: gnome-terminal, fonts, gvim

After upgrading to 17.10, the letter spacing for fonts has changed at 7pt (above looks okay to me, although it might simply not be so apparent).

Here is a screenshot from gvim from before the upgrade (excuse the poor quality):
[image: gvim before 17.10]

And here's a screenshot afterwards:
[image: gvim after 17.10]

There is also more space between lines, but it's the letter spacing that's bugging me.

The font is Monospace 7, but the same spacing issue is evident on other fonts too.

So the current letter spacing looks wrong, and not consistent with other font sizes, does anybody know a way to get the original spacing back?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but unfortunately it's not uncommon for fonts to change across releases, see e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fontconfig/+bug/1547374. You can try smaller (even non-integer) font sizes, e.g. `6.8`, does that help?

Comment: Interesting, in fact `6.8pt` seems to have brought it back to exactly the same letter width as `7pt` in the prior release, nice guess. :) There's slightly more spacing between lines, but that doesn't bother me in the slightest. If you want to add this as an answer that would be good because although it might not exactly be a solution, it is a workaround that may help others.